# Swift UITableView with a datasouce of different data types

Tags: swift, uitableview, model, datasource

From the JSON file, I create a model. It has several different types.
In my view I have a segmentedControl, where user can choose a type and filter the `tableView` accordingly.

```
private enum Section {
    case all(???)
    case case1(items: [type1])
    case case2(items: [type2])
    case case3(items: [type3])
}

    switch section {
    case .type1(let items):
        setupCell(items)
    case .type2(let items):
        setupCell(items)
    case .type3(let items):
        setupCell(items)
    }
```

The problem appears if I want to have a segment All and show all 3 types together. It means I would have an array of type `Any [type1, type2, type3]` and need to cast every type.
What would be the be approach to handle this use-case? Create a protocol that every type should conform? Is there some better approach?

Comment: A protocol is probably the best solution

Comment: The issue is that not each type has all the properties. Some of them would be optional. Probably the protocol extension is needed.

Comment: Bit you are going to view them in the table view right? Then they need a common interface. But other than that I don’t see how we can help you with so little information

Comment: It depends. Will you show the same thing in type1, type2 type3 cells? If yes, I'd prefer use a CustomTableViewCellModel, with a custom init with type1, type2, and type3 instance, instead of a protocol, that could collide with properties names... If the cells (and what they show) are really different, either create a ViewModel for each type, or use directly the type1 type2, type3 (it's question then between "time" and "better" coding).

Comment: I'll create a cell model for those item type. example cellModel func init(type:type1), and handle same model type in table.